# Working with huge quantity of float matrices

Tags: c++, optimization, memory-management, matrix

Ok I'm actually working with in-memory storage of huge quantities of float matrices. These matrices stores statistics data and most of the time, just a few cells contain non-null value.

Lets consider this simple problem.
An item collects statistics over time. These statistics are stored in single-line format matrix of about 30 float entries. But we also have, for an item, different kind of statistics. Then for an item, we can define this simple structure:

```
struct ItemStatistics
{
  uint64_t item_id;
  float * statistics_a;
  ...
  float * statistics_z;
};
```

While the application (server) is running, I collect a bunch of statistics for thousands of items. We then can define a global structure that stores application statistics for all our items as a map for fast access:

```
typedef std::map<uint64_t, ItemStatistics*> StatisticsDb; // item_id <-> statistics
```

This naive representation is not memory consumption efficient because every *statistics_x* object is a fix sized array of about 30 entries. As, in average, just 5 values are collected, the matrices are most of the time 10% full, sometimes less.

Is there a memory efficient way to store those data?

Is there a way to avoid malloc overhead for each matrix allocation? (For a million items and 4 kind of statistics, we have about 4 million malloc operations, without taking into account the std::map insert overhead...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe SparseLib++ could be something you're interested in. Take a look and see if it suits your needs: http://math.nist.gov/sparselib++/

> SparseLib++ is a C++ class library for
>   efficient sparse matrix computations
>   across various computational
>   platforms.

Comment: Sparse Matrix are just THE way to save memory comsumption. Thanks for the tip. I also found sparse_matrix from boost::numeric::ublas.